# Evento ao clique do mouse

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toca').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#msg-toca').show();
    });
  $('#toca').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#msg-toca').hide();
    });
});
```

como faço para ele trocar a mensagem ao clique do mouse?
Tentei com onclick e onClick, mas não funciona.

Comment: Com jQuery seria apenas `.click(function () {})`, seguindo o mesmo padrão que utilizou em `mouseenter` e `mouseleave` que não possuem o `on`

Comment: Eu tentei, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Poderia nos mostrar o que fez em um [mcve]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vc tem um evento `mouseenter/mouseleave` para ter algo similar com clique vc tem que fazer um `toggle()`, ou seja no primeiro clique "ativa" e no segundo clique "desativa"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então seu código ficaria assim

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toca').click(function(){
        $('#msg-toca').toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
#msg-toca {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<button id="toca">btn clica</button>
<div id="msg-toca">meu texto oculto</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se sua ideia seria somente trocar exibir ou esconder seu elemento utilizando um clique, o que você pode fazer seria verificar se o mesmo esta visível ou não, e esconde-lo utilizando `is(":visible")` do JQuery. [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/jf1u0c43/1/) com ambos os exemplos.

Para utilizado seria:

```
$(document).ready(() => {

    $('#toca').on('click', (e) => {
      if ($('#msg-troca').is(":visible"))
        $('#msg-troca').hide();
      else
        $('#msg-troca').show();
    });
});
```

Agora se sua ideia seja trocar o texto, o que você pode fazer e definir o text e verificar e mudar seu conteúdo:

```
$(document).ready(() => {

    $('#toca').on('click', (e) => {
      if ($('#msg-troca').text() === 'Texto 2')
        $('#msg-troca').text('Texto 1');
      else
        $('#msg-troca').text('Texto 2');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -4):

Boa tarde.

Tente usar o javascript puro, sem JQuery e ve se funciona

Vai no elemento dentro do formulario html id="toca" e coloque evento onclick=" $('#msg-toca').hide();"

ex:

$('#msg-toca').hide(); é um exemplo, recomendo que no arquivo js referenciado crie uma function.

ex: function Teste(){
  alert('Click');
}

no html na div

ve se funciona via javascript puro